# Which ma belongs in the phrase 我 "ma" 好的

Tags: character-identification

This may be a SE dialect thing, but plenty of my friends say 我 "ma" 好的 to mean 我很好 or "ma" 好的 to mean good or I agree with you.

Can someone tell me which character (if there is one) is supposed to be used here?

Comment: I've also only ever head 'man' - you don't have to be too far south to hear this though. At least, all my Wuhanese friends talk this way..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean "man" instead of "ma"?
If so, it's 蛮.

> 我蛮好的.

Answer (score 1):

Some people might write “我满好的”, but it is NOT in a *professional* style.

However, I found it seems that Taiwanese prefers to write “满好” but not “蛮好”.

It is best to be wary of it:)